# Is there a term for this number theoretic object?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology, prime-factorization

Given integer $N$ let $N=\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}p_i^{a_i}$ be its unique prime factorization where $p_i$ are distinct primes (a total of $\omega(N)$ of them).

> Is there a name for $\sum_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{a_i}$?

Comment: Hardy and Wright introduce it as the "total number of prime factors" (in contrast to $\omega(n)$ being the number of different prime factors).

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega(n)$.  See [OEIS sequence A001222](https://oeis.org/A001222).

Comment: is there a terminology that people use?

Comment: $\Omega(n)$ or "Omega$(n)$" or "Bigomega$(n)$".

Comment: haha does it show up in google scholar?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n) = \sum_{p^k \| n}  k $$

Also note $f(n) = \sum_{p^k | n} 1$ so that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s} = \zeta(s) \sum_{p^k} p^{-sk}$$

From which we can deduce the asymptotic and even an explicit formula for $\sum_{n \le x} f(n)$

Comment: what is the name?